# CDN Richtext editor in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dojo, cdn, rich-text-editor

With Dojo I can get a rich text editor with **4 lines** of HTML and without putting any JavaScript files on my server:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
data-dojo-config="isDebug: true,parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> dojo.require("dijit.Editor"); </script>
<textarea data-dojo-type="dijit.Editor" name="body" rows="10"
  cols="60" class="claro"></textarea>
```

I'm considering switching to jQuery. Can I do something like that with it?

Are there any jQuery CDN rich text editors available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your going to find this with jQuery, or tinyMCE or ckeditor or anything, because this feature depends on cross-domain loading.  Dojo has good baked in support for this.

I see jquery hosted on CDNs, but no plugins.